# Android ScrollView disable fling

Tags: android, scrollview

I don't want my scrollview to fling, only scroll normally. I found this class which overrides ScrollView,but since I'm new in Android, I don't know how to use it. Any ideas?

> import android.content.Context; import android.util.AttributeSet;
>   import android.widget.ScrollView;
>
> public class ScrollViewNoFling extends ScrollView {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param context
>  * @param attrs
>  * @param defStyle
>  */
> public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context) {
>
>     super(context);
>     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> }
> public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>
>     super(context, attrs);
>     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> }
> public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>
>     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> }
>
> @Override
> public void fling (int velocityY)
> {
>     /*Scroll view is no longer gonna handle scroll velocity.
>      * super.fling(velocityY);
>     */
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Don't do this! It ruins the UX, the user is used to being able to fling. Disabling the fling is poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say this custom class works, and your package is `com.example.app`, you can use your sutom view class in your `layout.xml` file like this

```
       <com.example.app.ScrollViewNoFling 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ...
        />
```

But you can just start typing inside your IDE the first couple of letters of your package and it will probably show up.

Also you can find this custom view inside View browser inside your IDE (probably on the bottom of the list)

Hope this helps.